# How to reference siblings (elements have the same parent) in lua script

Tags: lua, roblox

I hope the title is descriptive enough. Essentially, I want to have my code to manipulate another child of the element's parent. So if I had code in c in the example: a<b&c , then how do I get to c? Sorry if already posted a million times/is obvious, don't know terminology :)

Comment: Please post some actual Lua code to more clearly demonstrate what you're asking for.

Comment: `b.parent.children.c`, assuming you have both `parent` and `children` defined. Without code it's just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The question description doesn't help a bit, but trying to infer what you mean, you can get the children of a object (for this example, we will use the workspace) in LuaU like this

```
workspace:GetChildren()
```

And iterate like so

```
for i,v in pairs(workspace:GetChildren()) do print(v.Name) end
```